# React component doesn't unload correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a project that's for a coding challenge, and I am having trouble with routing. I have a post-register setup that requires the user to either fill out security questions or address, or upload a profile picture. The problem when the user logs in, and those things aren't set, he gets sent to the /setup route correctly, but the /settings component loads instead. I have lazy loading. But I have taken lazy loading out on all of the components to no avail. I have also moved around the routes. Added 'exact' just to see if it would do anything, but nothing. I get no error messages, nothing. Here's the heroku url to the app if you want to see the error for yourself. https://jetcakes-project.herokuapp.com. Feel free to create a user, or just use the test user:

**Email**: test@user.com 
**Password**: Password1

Here is my routing page:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.scss';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store, persistor } from './redux/ConfigureStore'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import Main from './components/MainPage/Main';
import AuthGuard from './components/AuthGuard/AuthGuard';

const Setup = React.lazy(
    () => import('./components/Setup/Setup')
)

const Dashboard = React.lazy(
    () => import('./components/Dashboard/Dashboard')
)

const Settings = React.lazy(
    () => import('./components/Settings/Settings')
)

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/">
                            <Main />
                        </Route>

                        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                            <AuthGuard to="/setup">
                                <Setup />
                            </AuthGuard>
                        </Suspense>

                        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                            <AuthGuard to="/settings">
                                <Settings />
                            </AuthGuard>
                        </Suspense>


                        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                            <AuthGuard path="/dashboard">
                                <Dashboard />
                            </AuthGuard>
                        </Suspense>
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

And here's my AuthGuard incase it helps:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export default function AuthGuard({ children, ...rest }) {
    const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.user.isAuthenticated),
        token = useSelector(state => state.user.token),
        email = useSelector(state => state.user.email),
        hasSecurity = useSelector(state => state.user.hasSecurity),
        hasAddress = useSelector(state => state.user.hasAddress),
        hasProfilePic = useSelector(state => state.user.hasProfilePic),
        location = useLocation()

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={() => {
                if (isAuthenticated && token && email) {
                    if (!hasSecurity || !hasAddress || !hasProfilePic) {
                        if (location.pathname !== '/setup') {
                            return <Redirect to="/setup" />
                        } else { return children }
                    } else {
                        return children
                    }
                } else {
                    return <Redirect to="/" />
                }
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mega faceplam**

I had typed on my /setup and /settings AuthGuard `to={path}` instead of `path={path}`